# Javascript gives incorrect comparison results

Tags: javascript

I simplified a problem I encountered to this:

On say, Chrome browser, press F12, and type the following into Console:

```
a=(0.005/10000).toExponential();
"5e-7"
  b=(0.04/10000).toExponential();
"4e-6"
  a<b
false
  a>b
true
  a.valueOf < b.valueOf
false
  a.valueOf() < b.valueOf()
false
  valueOf(a) < valueOf(b)
false
```

In this case, a < b should be true. All above boolean valuations are incorrect. How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential)

> **`toExponential`** Returns a string representing the Number object in exponential notation

You are comparing strings and not numbers.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I thought I did conversion by using `valueOf()`, but apparently `parseFloat()` is the way to go.